# Jenkins not finding powershell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm getting this error when I tried to run a Windows Powershell command in my biuld. I don't know how to add Powershell.exe to this? This was a plugin and I have no idea where it's located or how to use it.

```
[DeploymentTest] $ powershell.exe -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy ByPass "& '/tmp/jenkins8870821876113230026.ps1'"
FATAL: command execution failed
java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
```

.
.
.

```
Caused: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "powershell.exe" (in directory "/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/DeploymentTest"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: Looks like you are running it on a Linux box. You need to have a windows box for running powershell

Comment: oOoo wow you're right. beautiful.

Comment: Glad it helped! can you up vote my comment?

Comment: Glad it helped! can you up vote my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running it on a Linux box.Please switch over to a Windows box as you need Windows to run powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running dotnet/powershell on Linux, use a shell step and call the linux powershell executable `/usr/bin/pwsh` within it.  Here's an example working for me on a dotnet5 debian container:

```
stage('PreBuild') {
  steps {
    sh '''
      wget -v  https://aka.ms/install-artifacts-credprovider.ps1
      /usr/bin/pwsh -File ./install-artifacts-credprovider.ps1 -AddNetfx

      dotnet --version

      # reset the nuget credentials
      dotnet nuget update source "infrastructure"
    '''
  }
}
```